# Documentation for Transfrag class codes (cuffcompare)

Tags: transcriptome

Is there any extensive documentation or description for each class of Transfrag class codes as reported by the cuffcompare tool in the Cufflinks package?

[Official doc](http://cole-trapnell-lab.github.io/cufflinks/cuffcompare/#transfrag-class-codes) might not be the best.

E.g. what does *contained* mean (class code: c)? Or, what is a *generic exonic overlap* (class code: o)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a bit more information by [looking at the source code comments](https://github.com/cole-trapnell-lab/cufflinks/blob/b55bb214ad4abeb58a1435d8f7a7f0dd8bed8b76/src/gff_utils.cpp). [Contained](https://github.com/cole-trapnell-lab/cufflinks/blob/b55bb214ad4abeb58a1435d8f7a7f0dd8bed8b76/src/gff_utils.cpp#L140-L141) is for single exon transcripts that are primarily contained ([>80% overlap](https://github.com/cole-trapnell-lab/cufflinks/blob/b55bb214ad4abeb58a1435d8f7a7f0dd8bed8b76/src/gff_utils.cpp#L145)) within an exon of an already annotated transcript. `Generic exonic overlap` is for cases where a transfrag exon overlaps that of an annotated transcript. The strand doesn't seem to matter in such cases.